# the matching wildcard is strict but no declaration can be found for element 'osgi:service'

Tags: java, spring, osgi

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi">
```

**These are the errors I get:**

- the matching wildcard is strict but no declaration can be found for element 'osgi:service'
- the matching wildcard is strict but no declaration can be found for element 'osgi:reference'

Comment: +1, this class of issues is a quite common pitfall with Spring XML configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the version to the shemaLocation in line 6.

You can find all Versions here (line 5): http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi">
```